# Executing callback in ascending order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Attached is the problem and the solution code I wrote. Basically callback should console log the output in ascending order not the order in which it received.

```
function processRequest(i, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback('Action processed ' + i);
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

callAction(6);

callAction(count) {
  //write code here
}
```

expected output>>

```
    Action processed 1
    Action processed 2
    Action processed 3
    Action processed 4
    Action processed 5
    Action processed 6
```

I know this is not the best way to solve this. Can someone rate my solution and possibly suggest a better way? Something Async I am guessing?

Much appreciated! Thanks.

```js
function processRequest(i, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback('Action processed ' + i);
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

callAction(6);

function callAction(count) {
  const arr = [];
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    arr[i - 1] = i;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    processRequest(i, function(str) {
      counter++;
      let currentActionNum = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/g));
      let message = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(currentActionNum));
      if (currentActionNum === arr[0]) {
        console.log(message + currentActionNum);
        arr.shift();
      }
      if (counter === count) {
        for (let i = arr[0]; i <= count; i++) {
          console.log(message + i);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I was asking this during an interview and I feel I didn't do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the interviewer want you to do is to make sure these processes would run in the right order (the 'real-life' process would be different, not just print some string). So, here is a better solution:

```
function callAction(count){
    i = 1;
    cb = function(str){
        console.log(str)
        count-i++ && processRequest(i, cb) //'same' as: if (count-i++>0) then ...
    }    
    processRequest(1, cb)
}
```

Just out of curiosity, may I ask if it is a face to face interview? Do you have access to a computer? How long do you have to solve this? If I dont have a computer with me to try and test then I might do worst than that...

Answer (score 0):

Your task is not to use super-complicated processing to rewrite the outputs to appear in the correct order, but to ensure that the 6 processes run sequentially. You can do that with a simple recursive approach:

```
function callAction(count) {
    if (count > 1)
        processRequest(7 - count, result => {
//                     ^^^^^^^^^ ok, that part is a bit weird
            console.log(result);
            callAction(count - 1);
        });
}
```